# How to serialize POD structures automatically (with no use of .proto files) into Protocol Buffer?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, protocol-buffers

Say we have int, float and two strings in a struct. We want to serialize (on Windows x86) send over internet and deserialize our relatively POD based struct (on Linux x64). I like protobufs approach that makes that data serializable across different languages, but sometimes you just want to say something like:

```
my_obj var;
string data =protobuf.serialize(var);

my_obj new_war = protobuf.deserialize(data);
```

and not care what fields you had in your structure. So I wonder if it is possible and how to magically serialize POD alike data (say all that is friend with boost serialization and all types that [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) support out of the box) containing structures into [Protocol Buffer](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html)?

Comment: Please, for the love of all that's holy, *don't send floats*!

Answer (score 1):

You could define a Protobuf schema to represent a POD struct as a collection of name and value pairs, where each value is a union of primitive types, however the real problem is that C++ has no way of introspecting an arbitrary type. So somewhere in your code you would need to provide a description of your type.

BTW, Protobuf serialises to binary data, not strings.